# Erro ao tentar executar o nodemon

Tags: javascript, json, npm, yarn

Boa tarde, estou com problema ao tentar executar o nodemon no meu terminal. Ele está apresentando a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
C:\Users\juare\Desktop\Curso OmniStack\aulas\backend> yarn dev  
yarn run v1.16.0  
$ nodemon src/index.js  
`nodemon` não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.  
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Parece que você não tem o `nodemon` instalado. Deveria estar instalado?

Comment: `npm i -g nodemon`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss e @Sorack ele faz uso do yarn, acredito que o `yarn install` já resolveria. @JuarezSimone pode adicionar a dúvida o conteúdo do seu `package.json`? Eu coloquei uma resposta com algumas opções (inclusive com npm).

Answer (score 3):

Existe duas maneiras para você resolver o problema. A primeira é você instalar a biblioteca `nodemon` através do comando `npm install -g nodemon`.

Você também pode fazer a instalação como uma dependência de desenvolvimento para o projeto (`npm install nodemon --save-dev`) e na sessão scripts do arquivo `package.json` colocar a instrução abaixo:

```
...
"scripts": {
...
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js"
...
}
...
```

> Observação: os ... são para demonstrar que não só pode como deve existir conteúdos do arquivo antes e depois das instruções.

Após fazer a instalação do pacote e colocar a instrução acima no `package.json`, basta executar o comando `npm run dev`. Gostaria de falar que essa segunda opção, eu gosto bastante, pois ao executar o `npm install` o sistema também já vai fazer a instalação de todas as dependências para o desenvolvimento do projeto.

Notei que você faz uso do `yarn` é possível que você já possua esses passos realizados. Experimente executar um `yarn install` e depois execute o comando novamente.

Comment: Vlw!!  muito obrigado pela dica, consegui resolver. :)

Comment: @JuarezSimone Favor ler [como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO! Só consegui fazer funcionar seguindo a dica do comentário acima. Está mais pra bug no meu caso, pois se eu rodo "nodemon index.js" ou "nodemon src/index.js" o terminal retorna um erro, porém, rodando "yarn run dev" o nodemon funciona sem problemas. Vai entender né.